# zipped file in json or zipped file with json

Tags: python, json, zip, pyramid

I need return response from pyramid with zipped file, and some additional info.

I can add this info as special file to zipfile.
or I can send sth like json with one value with zipfile.

I already have code written, but 
both seems to be little tricky (like dirty hacks) and I do not see other possibility, do not even see cons and pros of above mentioned.

Comment: And the question is.. */dramatic music* ..what?

Comment: and the question is ../do you see better solution/ for such mix of data

Comment: Please ask the relevant question also. And include the necessary code if you want us to judge or specify which one is safer.

Comment: You do not give any details, but I guess that if you have to give data in json and also give a zipped file, I would do that in 2 different URLS, like /some-resources/3 for meta and /some-resources/3/file for file.

Comment: @Antoine: ... because now I know that is no nice solution for this. you are wrong with 2 urls as I need mixed stuff in single http response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you yourself are handling the response then definitely go for the easier or *whatever you are comfortable with* code.

Else (which is most likely the case) check what the end user or client can better handle. Also, safer code should be preferred even if it has dirty hacks.

Edit - Not a good SO answer, but comments are dirty :/